# Speeding up echarts setOption and Datazoom

Tags: javascript, echarts

This is a general question.
I render large amounts of data (5million+ datapoints) and part of my chart flow is some user-interactive data. For example, a user may brush-select a region of the chart, and then I turn that section into a markArea for clarity.

To create these markAreas, I use setOption().
However given the massive amount of data, I believe it takes a long time to merge these new options together. Is there a general strategy for speeding that up? I only apply markArea to a single grid, but I believe echarts is checking to make sure nothing needs to be re-rendered. I have animation disabled.

Additionally, I have a datazoom to navigate around the data.

Important note: I'm using 20 grids simultaneously (actually a variable number) to render 20 separate lines; I do this to allow me to organize the lines on the screen in a clean way. Thus I configure my datazoom to be active across all 20 grids. How badly might this be impacting my performance?

Comment: Via profiling, I also see that setOption() takes a massive time for big data, especially due to "arrayDiff" which compares the previous and new options. Did you find a solution/workaround? Recreating the whole graph maybe?